# Hovering over menu item removes left border. How do I leave menu border on hover?

Tags: html, css

I've got a menu made that utilizes left and right borders to separate each menu item. When hovering over the menu, the background changes to a lighter shade, which is what I want. However, hovering also covers the left border. How can I stop the border from disappearing? I'm sure this has been answered elsewhere, but I couldn't find it. Thanks, in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/aYsKp/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
<div id="menu">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="products.html">PRODUCTS</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="videos.html">VIDEOS</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="downloads.html">DOWNLOADS</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    width:960px;
    margin: 10px auto 5px auto;
    background-color: #727272;
}
#menu {
    max-width:828px;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    font: 12px/18px sans-serif;
}
#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
    padding: 10px 32px;
    color:#FFF;
}
#menu ul {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
}
#menu ul li:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid #FFF;
}
#menu ul li:hover {
    background-color:#818181;
}
```

Comment: Try changing `#menu ul li:first-child {}` to `#menu ul li{}` in your CSS. Right now that style gives a border to your first child but not the rest. Removing it will give the border to all of them. Alternatively, change it to `#menu ul li:hover {}` or basically just move the `border-left` property into the existing `#menu ul li:hover` selector section.

Comment: This helped. I changed border-right to border-left on #menu ul li{} and then added a border-right to #menu ul li:last-child{}. Thanks!

Comment: Not that hard, check this: http://jsfiddle.net/nightire/aYsKp/3/, only two line changes

Comment: All good now guys/gals. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Try this approach.](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminabel/pRQ4A/)

```
#header {
    width:960px;
    margin: 10px auto 5px auto;
}
#menu {
    max-width:828px;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    font: 12px/18px sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
}
#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
    padding: 10px 32px;
    color:#FFF;
}
#menu ul {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;    
     background-color: #727272;
    margin:0;
}
#menu ul li:hover {
    background-color:#818181;
}
```

What I've done is just removed right margin and specified background color as white for the menu div.

Answer (score 0):

I use to set border or space informations in A tag, not in LI, making LI like an "invisible" tag, setting all properties to A, using A display:inline-block.